# How can I start a Jupyter notebook with specific context?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm writing an Flask extension named [Flask-ShellPlus](https://github.com/kxxoling/flask-shellplus),
and intend to add an `--notebook` option for `shell` command, which should start an Jupyter server and create an notebook page with specific context as I set for IPython shell.

How can I implement this?

Comment: what is `context` in this context?

Comment: @cel Flask app context, basically database models. Only SQLAlchemy is supported now.